# how to exclude character if a certain character occurs earlier

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to validate US telephone numbers
and i'm trying to exclude
555)555-5555 and (555-555-5555

How do i exclude the '(' if there's no ')' after the 3rd 5
and vice versa?

Comment: is this valid  format 111-111-1111 once you exclude parentheses ?

Comment: Yes, thats Valid format

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about something simple:
https://regex101.com/r/g6uBF4/1

```
^((\(\d{3}\))|(\d{3}-))\d{3}-\d{4}
```

Just test for each case separately. Either 3 digits enclosed in parenthesis `(\d{3}\)` or `|` 3 digits with a dash `(\d{3}-)`. Then the rest of the number `\d{3}-\d{4}`.

Answer (score 1):

my suggestion is to auto format the number while entering it, see the demo below

```js
$(function() {

  $('#us-phone-no').on('input', function() {

    var value = $(this).val();

    var nums = value.replace(/\D/g, '').match(/(\d{0,3})(\d{0,3})(\d{0,4})/);
    var formated = !nums[2] ? nums[1] : nums[1] + '-' + nums[2] + (nums[3] ? '-' + nums[3] : '');

    $(this).val(formated);
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="tetx" id="us-phone-no">
```

Answer (score 0):

In general, you can't use Javascript regexes to ensure that parentheses are correctly balanced if there can be an indefinite number of nested parentheses. You'd need recursive/balanced matching for that. But your case is not that complicated.

For example, you can add a [negative lookahead assertion](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) at the start of your regex:

```
/^(?![^()]*[()][^()]*$)REST_OF_REGEX_HERE/
```

This ensures that there won't be a single opening or closing parenthesis in your input.

**Explanation:**

```
^       # Start of string
(?!     # Assert that it's impossible to match...
 [^()]* #  any number of characters other than parentheses,
 [()]   #  then a single parenthesis,
 [^()]* #  then any number of characters other than parentheses,
 $      #  then the end of the string.
)       # End of lookahead
```

Of course there may be other ways to do what you need, but you didn't show us the rest of the rules you're using for matching.